# Install ubuntu to thinkPad T540

Tags: hardware

I tried to install ubuntu to thinkPad T540, the default image throw system halt error. I found special release for this notebook, but I coudn't download this. Where can I find iso for this release?

Comment: Where have you read that there is a special version of Ubuntu for Lenovo T540?

Comment: Here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201309-14211/ , I known official it is for manufactures, but can I get for home installing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and state which version you were trying to install. If you experience an issue with like a crash or system halt during installation with a non-EOL version, then this is likely to be a bug that should be filed on the Launchpad bugtracker. You should make a screenshot or photo when there is an error message (or logfiles). If you tried 12.04, please try again with 14.04.01 or a more recent version.

Comment: You probably got this wrong, in certain regions you can buy this laptop with Ubuntu preinstalled. I don't think that you can call customer support and they will provide you the image and none else probably has this or is allowed to provide you access.

Answer (score 0):

You can only ask Lenovo if they provide you with the image or installation media or check their website, there's no download for this available from ubuntu.

Perhaps a standard image would work, just try it.